# Turn a Test Class using static method into a service Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, constructor, controller, static

I am using Drools as validators for my Validation Mechanism in a messaging system.

I want to convert part of my local testing console Application into a service.
Used Springboot + Thymleaf everything ok with other classes but i would like to validate some messages from the exposed service.

The problem is that i use a superclass ( DroolsTest  )that i inherit in my test classes.

Turning this into a controller does not seem to work.

I get Nullpointer exceptions for the constructor part .

```
   super("myParameter",RULE_FILES);
```

How could i convert this into a Controller.?
It might be really easy but i am really confused.

Thank you in Advance Guys.

**This snippet is the one that works locally.**

```
public class messageToTest_Test **extends DroolsTest** {

    public static String[] RULE_FILES;

    static {
        RefDataXmlPath ref = new RefDataXmlPath();
        ref.updateXmlPathbaseOnPhase(Phase.myParameter, Iteration.myParameter);

        GetInformationFromXmlMapping getRulesFromXmlMapping = new GetInformationFromXmlMapping();
        String rules[] = getRulesFromXmlMapping.getRulesByMessages(Iteration.myParameter, Phase.myParameter, "messageToTest").toArray(new String[0]);
        RULE_FILES = rules;
    }

    public messageToTest_Test() throws IOException {
        super("myParameter",RULE_FILES);


    }

    @Test
    public void messageToTest_Test_1() throws Exception {
      SOME CODE HERE.....
        }
    }
```

Constructor in DroolsTest Class

```java
public DroolsTest( String iteration, String... ruleFiles) {
  this.RULES_PATH = "Rules/" + iteration + "/";
  this.ruleFiles = ruleFiles;
  this.MESSAGES_PATH = "src/test/resources/XML_Messages/" + iteration + "/";
}
```

Comment: Could you add the constructor of `DroolsTest` and the exception?

Comment: I added the requested part.
I get NullPointer in ruleFiles

How to pass these values inside the controller?

Answer (score 0):

> I get Nullpointer exceptions for the constructor part .

You can call constructors of inherited classes only in constructors of the current one. `super("myParameter",RULE_FILES)` would initialize a class, but it doesn't work like that in a method since the methode itself can be called only when the class was already initalized. (I don't understand how your IDE didn't mark this as invalid syntax.)

If you need to set-up some properties before your tests start and you have access to those fields, use [@Before, @BeforeTest @BeforeAll etc.](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-before-beforeclass-beforeeach-beforeall)

```
public class MessageToTest_Test **extends DroolsTest** {

  public static String[] RULE_FILES;

  @BeforeClass
  public static void beforeClass() {
      RefDataXmlPath ref = new RefDataXmlPath();
      ref.updateXmlPathbaseOnPhase(Phase.myParameter, Iteration.myParameter);

      GetInformationFromXmlMapping getRulesFromXmlMapping = new GetInformationFromXmlMapping();
      String rules[] = getRulesFromXmlMapping.getRulesByMessages(Iteration.myParameter, Phase.myParameter, "messageToTest").toArray(new String[0]);
      super.ruleFiles = rules;
      ...
  }

  @Before
  public void beforeEachTest () {
     /*.. other things ..*/
  }

  public messageToTest_Test() throws IOException {
      /*... test ...*/

  }
}
```

If you don't have access, use the default constructor to setup:

```
public class MessageToTest_Test **extends DroolsTest** {

  public static String[] RULE_FILES;

  static {
      RefDataXmlPath ref = new RefDataXmlPath();
      ref.updateXmlPathbaseOnPhase(Phase.myParameter, Iteration.myParameter);

      GetInformationFromXmlMapping getRulesFromXmlMapping = new GetInformationFromXmlMapping();
      String rules[] = getRulesFromXmlMapping.getRulesByMessages(Iteration.myParameter, Phase.myParameter, "messageToTest").toArray(new String[0]);
      RULE_FILES = rules;
  }

   MessageToTest_Test () {
     super("myParameter",RULE_FILES);
   }
   ...
}
```

> How could i convert this into a Controller.?

Don't understand exactly what you mean by that. If you want to test settings seperately - extract them in a separate class and test it as a component which you could pass in the constructor.